# Chrome debugger on a breakpoint, the variable data should pop up in a yellow dialog if hovered over with a mouse. That is no longer working

Tags: google-chrome, variables, debugging

The following issue seems to have reappeared in the latest chrome "Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)" any ideas?

Until recently, when paused in Chrome debugger on a breakpoint, the current state of a JavaScript variable, array or object would pop up in a yellow dialog if hovered over with a mouse. That is no longer working though I'm at a loss to know what has changed. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Downgraded Chrome and stopped it updating, all working again.  Not Ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem with the same version of Chrome. While waiting for a Chrome update, I recommend switching to Chromium. https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/